# Producing small Windows binaries

Tags: windows, winsxs

When developing and deploying native Windows applications, I often need to install a runtime before being able to run my binary, or statically link the library with my binary. For instance, after building a "Win32 Console" project with Visual Studio 2008, attempting to run the program on a fresh Windows 7 image results in:

> The application has failed to start because its side-by-side configuration is incorrect. Please see the application event log or use the command-line sxstrace.exe tool for more detail.

Issues like this one have been brought up in [other posts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19047/tortoisesvn-side-by-side-configuration-is-incorrect) on StackOverflow.

How does one develop applications that *don't* require runtimes that aren't already on the target OS (i.e. don't require installing redistributable packages or private/shared side-by-side assemblies)? How does one avoid using msvc[mpr]90.dll and just use the Windows API in \windows\system32*.{dll,sys}?

I'm thinking along the lines of the code that comes out of the demoscene, but that's frequently not made available.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Others have already responded with respect to linking CRT statically. If you also want a small binary at the same time, then your best bet is forego CRT entirely, and use only Win32 API functions as much as possible. You'll still get some CRT code, most notably related to startup (i.e. that which calls `main`) and shutdown (`atexit` handling etc), but otherwise the linker won't link CRT functions that you do not use.

You can avoid linking CRT altogether by using `/Zl` compiler switch. This means that `main` will no longer work, however - you'll need to define `WinMain` (name doesn't matter, but signature must match, and it must be `__stdcall`), and you will have to specify the name of your `WinMain`-like function as an entry point via linker `/entry:` switch. This will save you ~30Kb of CRT code (tested on a .cpp with an empty `main`).

If you go the latter route, you might also have to deal with issue of compiler intrinsics. There are some functions that are nominally defined by the CRT (and declared in its headers), but which are treated specially by the compiler, so that it inserts optimized assembly instructions at the point of the call where possible - examples are `memset`, `strlen`, and a good chunk of functions in `<math.h>`; a complete list can be found [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/tzkfha43.aspx). Since you don't have CRT, if you need these functions, or could avoid it but prefer the intrinsic because of improved performance (hard to do better than `memset`, for example), then you have to declare them yourself, and use `#pragma intrinsic`. E.g.:

```
// Contains macros and typedef only, so safe to include without CRT.
// We need it here for size_t.
#include <stddef.h> 

extern "C"
{
    int abs(int);
    void* memset(void*, int, size_t); 
}

#pragma intrinsic(abs, memset)

int __stdcall main(void*, void*, char*, int)
{
    char tmp[10];
    memset(tmp, abs(-123), 10);
    return 0;
}
```

The above can be compiled with:

```
cl /c /Zl foo.cpp
link /entry:main foo.obj
```

Answer (score 3):

Link the CRT statically via the `/MT` switch (and likewise MFC, if you're using it).

Static linking limits what you can do with DLLs somewhat, but for simple executables it works like a charm. (And if you're shipping DLLs, you can always ship private assemblies anyway.)

Answer (score 2):

Use the static CRT.  This doesn't create a dependency on msvc*.dll.  The CRT is linked directly into your program.  This doesn't create dependencies, but does increase the size of your executable.

More info on different CRT options [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/abx4dbyh(VS.80).aspx).

Answer (score 0):

Statically link the runtime. MS Visual C++ has option /MT for that (default is /MD)

Answer (score 0):

I think one way to do this is to just not use Visual Studio and instead rely on the command line SDK tools. (You can alternatively figure out how to config VS to do what you want, but that seems harder.) E.g.:

```
cl /c app.cpp
link app.obj ws2_32.lib
```

Comment: This will still bring in the CRT, and really is no different from using VS.

Comment: Yeah, you can tweak VS to do the same thing, but by default VS causes the problem in the original post to occur---something which doesn't happen when doing things in my suggested way. All the same, your answer was definitely the most enlightening outcome.